# How to get current culture for app.UseExceptionHandler method that in Startup.cs's Configure method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a multilingual web site that I writed ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC.

The it support two languages: Azerbaijan and English. The it use routing base localization.

I set  `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)` for use exception page, following as below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/main/error");
       app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/en/main/error", "?code={0}");
    ...
}
```

But I have a one problem. The problem it is my exception page always use `"en"` culture.

Because I set hardcode the errorEandlingPath of app.UseExceptionHandler. (`app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/main/error");` and  `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/en/main/error", "?code={0}");`)

My site's routing configurations following as below:

```
...
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{culture=az}/{controller=Main}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    }
...
```

How I can set current culture dynamically  in `app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/main/error");` ?

For example: If a user use Azerbaijan culture, errorEandlingPath must be `"/az/main/error"`, otherwise `"/en/main/error"`.

I tried

`app.UseExceptionHandler("/{culture}/main/error");` 
and

`app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{culture}/main/error", "?code={0}");`

but both are not working. Please help me, thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is a middleware lets call it `ExceptionHtmlHandler` and you have to get the `"Accept-Language"` from the Header to know from where is he coming from.
and you will need to control, based on the exception if you want to return a 404/403/etc.

This is the middleware:

```
public class ExceptionHtmlHandler
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHtmlHandler(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (YourException e)
        {
            context.RequestServices
                   .GetService<ILogger>()
                   .Error(e);

            PersonalizedMethod1(context, e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          context.RequestServices
                 .GetService<ILogger>()
                 .Error(e);
            HandleException(context, e);
        }
    }

    private static void PersonalizedMethod1(HttpContext context, Exception e)
    {
        var lang = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"];
        var errorCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        context.Response.StatusCode =(int)errorCode;
        context.Response.Redirect($"/{lang}/main/error/{errorCode}");
    }

    // other errors
    private static void HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception e)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/error");
    }
}
```

To use it in your `startup.cs` instead of `app.UseExceptionHandler("/en/main/error");` you can use `app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHtmlHandler>();`

Finally, for your controller, something like that will do, I don't think you need to use the routes:

```
[HttpGet("{lang}/main/error/{errorCode}")]
public async Task<ViewResult> Error(string lang,int errorCode )
{
    return View("Error", await GetErrorTranslated(lang,errorCode  ));
}
```

Comment: Hi my friend. Thanks you for idea. I try your code, that you used "Accept-Language" of Header. But"Accept-Language" of Header is empty in my code, therefore I check context.Request.Path for dedect culture. I finally decided that, rewrite own middleware on based UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute. I will check source code of UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute  or ExceptionHandlerMiddleware - https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/3a868d87a2458fd025ca71e2538b3a72f67c7c50/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs . The it is working for me. Thanks for idea